# Как сохранить перевод строк при чтении Edittext to String?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Читаю в строку Edittext.gettext , вывожу в диалоге - перевода строк нет. Ввожу -

```
Раз\n
Два\n
Три.
```

### Выводит - РазДваТри.

### в другом проекте (serg.stih - заучи стих) стихи с \n после каждой строки беру из ресурса и в диалоге выводится как надо.

Помогла тема https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java/4298836#4298836

Comment: Поподробнее, не понял.

Comment: если вы используете setTitle(String title), то никак вроде бы, можно не выводить title, а добавить multiline textview на диалог и вывести туда

Comment: Multiline есть. Ввожу на разных строках.но перевод строк не сохраняется.

Comment: Multiline не у EditText откуда берете, а у TextView который можно добавить на диалоговое окно (хотя он там вроде по умолчанию, но не уверен)

Comment: у TextView мультистрочность по умолчанию. а вот в диалоге у заголовка переносы в пробелы меняются.
setMessage в помощь.

Comment: текст выводится как-раз через setMessage . что копать-то ?

Comment: import java.io.*;

// ...

String literal = "\"Has \\\"\\\\\\\t\\\" & isn\\\'t \\\r\\\n on 1 line.\""; StreamTokenizer parser = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(literal)); String result; try { parser.nextToken(); if (parser.ttype == '"') { result = parser.sval; } else { result = "ERROR!"; } } catch (IOException e) { result = e.toString(); } System.out.println(result);